# williamchart using float in y axis android

Tags: android, charts, axis

I'm working on currency converter in android and I'm trying to display a graph between two currencies.  I'm using WilliamChart library but can't set the y axis using float. My values are with small difference like : 0.122, 0.13.
How can I make the y axis use float instead of int?

[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Airp1.png)

I tried setAxisBorderValues(0, valueMax) but I can't use float or double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment that isn't possible, the library forces labels to be Integer, no decimal places are taken into account.